# Best approach, multiple curved carriage ends

Tags: modeling, mesh

Working on a railway carriage and I'm looking for some opinions on the best way to approach the ends?

[image: Many curves, much wow]

The roof has a curve running accross it, as well as curved corners on the ends, the sides have a curve on the bottom and the top, though not as extreme as the roof, the windows are on a flat strip in the center. The end also has a boxy roof extrusion with curved edges. Anyone got a quick run down on how they would approach The end sections? Am I better off using multiple different meshes or extuding from one? It's doing my head in a little bit.

Thanks for helping a noob out! :)

Cheers

[image: aneurysm]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Begin with a cube, scale it, create 2 loopcuts:

[image]

Then delete 3/4 of the cube, give it a *Mirror* modifier on X and Y, bevel its top and bottom, then create an edge at its side:

[image]

Cut off a hole at the front and fill with orthogonal faces:

[image]

Bevel this angle (of course you'll need to correct the topology afterwards):

[image]

Extrude the top:

[image]

Then lower down, merge the vertices, etc:

[image]

As the wagon is made of different pieces you could also separate them.

Comment: although i am using Blender a few days, i have no idea how you made that...if i mirror a cube in edit mode (or do you mean modifier?) ...i already fail at step 1

Comment: @Chris yes I meant a Mirror modifier on X and Y   ;)

Comment: ok, thank you for that info. Now...i just used a default cube - no movement at all, added mirror modifier, how do i create that edge? mine looks like this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXIfl.png ...and since your edit mode looks totally different to mine, i assume i "forgot" to do....what? :D

Comment: you first need to delete 3/4 of your cube, then give it the Mirror modifier

Comment: sorry, i know i am modelling beginner, but how do i delete 3/4 of a cube? knife tool?

Comment: is it possible you just moved the cube in edit mode so that it is completely in positive xyz and one edge is on 0,0,0?

Comment: I've edited, create 2 loopcuts, then remove 3/4 of your object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140494/discussion-between-chris-and-moonboots).

Comment: @Chris you can join our Discord if you want me to show you  ;)

Comment: yes, show me, link to discord?

Comment: this one should work:  discord.gg/E6wXbR7A5S

Comment: Thank you so much. I was heading in the right direction, just getting more experienced opinions is always helpful. Thank you so much. :)